# HKStatisticsCollectionQuery response mismatch

Tags: ios, iphone, healthkit

When I query to  HKStatisticsCollectionQuery for retrieving data for more than one date for per minute steps.

I'm getting response mismatch means suppose I have query for 3 days data for per minute  I am getting response for 3 query first and then others so its mismatching.

If anything track solution or other solution its good to help us.

My code

-(void)stepsForMin:(NSDate *)startDate

{

```
// Query to get the user's latest weight, if it exists.

NSLog(@"ToDays date %@ ",startDate);

HKQuantityType *stepsType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *interval = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

interval.minute=1;

NSDateComponents *anchorComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];

anchorComponents.day = 1;

NSDate *anchorDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:anchorComponents];

// Create the query

HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query = [[HKStatisticsCollectionQuery alloc] initWithQuantityType:stepsType quantitySamplePredicate:nil options:HKStatisticsOptionCumulativeSum anchorDate:anchorDate intervalComponents:interval];

// Set the results handler

query.initialResultsHandler = ^(HKStatisticsCollectionQuery *query, HKStatisticsCollection *results, NSError *error)

{

    if (error)

    {

        // Perform proper error handling here

        NSLog(@"***Steps for calculate active point read Not Success = %@ ",error.description);

    }else{

        NSLog(@"@@@Steps for calculate active point read Success ");

    }

   NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    formatter.dateFormat = @"dd MMM yyyy";

    NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:startDate];

    NSLog(@" date is== %@",string);

    NSString *startTime = @"00:00:01";

    NSString *timestr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", string, startTime];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [formatter1 setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

    [formatter1 setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

    [formatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd LLLL yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate* startDate1 = [formatter1 dateFromString:timestr];

    NSString *endtime = @"23:59:59";

    NSString *timestr1 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", string, endtime];

    NSDate* endDate1 = [formatter1 dateFromString:timestr1];

    NSLog(@"Start Date in calcluate %@ EndDate %@",startDate1,endDate1);

    [results enumerateStatisticsFromDate:startDate1 toDate:endDate1 withBlock:^(HKStatistics *result, BOOL *stop) {

      HKQuantity *quantity = result.sumQuantity;

        if (quantity)

        {

    double value = [quantity doubleValueForUnit:[HKUnit countUnit]];

            NSString *stepsValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f",value];

            [stepsForactive addObject:stepsValue];

        }



    }];

    [self calulateActivePoints];

};

   [self.healthStore executeQuery:query];
```

}